# AWS Athena parse nested JSON array

Tags: json, amazon-athena

I have JSON files structured like this and I need to use AWS Athena to query this JSON to extract certain values in the `myarray` array.

End result should be `userIdentifier` and the `enabled` value only where title= `zz`

in this case, it'd be

```
useridentifier, enabled 
xyz-123, true
```

json

```
{
   "userIdentifier":"xyz-123",
   "myarray":[
      {
         "code":"split",
         "requiresinput":false,
         "categorycode":"strictly_necessary",
         "originalrequiresinput":false,
         "title":"xx",
         "enabled":false
      },
      {
         "code":"zz",
         "requiresinput":false,
         "categorycode":"zz",
         "originalrequiresinput":false,
         "title":"zz",
         "enabled":true
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this so sharing for others.

[image]

- set up a Glue table pointing to your s3 folder
- for the columns

  - set useridentifier - varchar (1000)
  - for myArray column - use Array data type and then string subtype

for the query, use the UNNEST command.

```
with cte1 AS
(
SELECT 
   
    useridentifier
    ,json_extract_scalar(source, '$.enabled') enabled
    ,"$path" pth
FROM "testdb"."test" 
CROSS JOIN UNNEST("testdb"."test"."myArray") AS t1 (source)
where json_extract_scalar(source, '$.title') = 'zz'
)
select 
    
    useridentifier
    ,enabled
    , pth
from cte1 c
```